# number with the most prime divisors

Tags: python

I've done a program and it works fine as I want to but I feel it could be better and more advanced so I want some master advice on my program which is going to take many numbers and return the number with the most prime divisors and the number of its divisors in front the number like this `678 3` as the output

code :

```
list_of_inputs = []
for elements in range(5):
    list_of_inputs.append(int(input()))
list_of_inputs = list(set(list_of_inputs))

def _check_prime_sample_(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    # Iterate from 2 to the number
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


def find_integer_with_most_divisors(input_list):
    from operator import itemgetter
    lis = []
    dic = {}
    for elements in input_list:
        sub_lis = []
        for items in range(1, elements):
            if elements % items == 0 and _check_prime_sample_(items) == True:
                sub_lis.append(items)
        lis.append(len(sub_lis))
        dic[elements] = len(sub_lis)
    tup = [(k, v) for k, v in dic.items()]
    sup = max(tup, key=itemgetter(1, 0))
  
    print('{} {}'.format((sup)[0], (sup)[1]))


find_integer_with_most_divisors(list_of_inputs)
```

Comment: If your programs works, and you'd like advice on how to improve it, perhaps https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable for your problem.

Comment: Do you mean I have to delete the question? I can't ask a question within the next forty minutes

Comment: First ask at CodeReview; if you get a positive response there, you should indeed delete your question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a function that returns the number of prime factors and use the max() function to get the result:

```
def primeFactors(N):
    count = 0
    p     = 2                   # prime candidate
    while p*p<=N:               # find primes up to √N
        n = N        
        while N%p == 0: N //= p # remove prime factor from N
        count += (n!=N)         # count factors
        p += 1 + p%2            # next prime candidate
    return count + (N>1)
```

output:

```
list_of_inputs = list(range(100))

count,number   = max( (primeFactors(n),n) for n in set(list_of_inputs) )

print(number,count) # 90 3
```